# Unable to perform EF migrations

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I cannot seem to successfully execute parts of the EF tooling, specifically migrations, using:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialDatabase
```

from the command line in the same directory that contains my project files using VS2015. I created a blank ASP.NET Core Web Application for a Pluralsight tutorial, but the tutorial was created a year ago using version 1.0.0 of the .NET SDK and Entity Framework Core 1.0.0. Since that time, .NET Core 1.1 has been released and the EF tooling has changed. I have tried various approaches to get migrations working, but I have been met with multiple types of errors such as:
1. A parameter-less constructor is required in the DbContext class.
2. When trying to workaround using a class that implements IDbContextFactory, it wants to implement a Create method with an argument of String[].
3. Trying to use migrations with NPM `Add-Migration InitialCreate` results in: 
`Startup project 'src\TheWorld' is an ASP.NET Core or .NET Core project for Visual Studio 2015. This version of the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of projects.` (which leads me to believe that I have improper EF packages and tooling versions.)

I should also mention that I do not have a `.csproj` file in my project. I only see an `.xproj` file. All dependencies are managed through `project.json`. Any advice would be extremely welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [.NET Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core) no longer supports project.json or Visual Studio 2015. Everyone doing .NET Core development is encouraged to [migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/articles/core/migration/) from project.json to csproj and [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/).